# For an initial GET request, where does conversion happens?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

> The `conversion` between `two UIInput instances` happens in the `Process`
>   `Validations` phase (default), which can be moved to `Apply Request`
>   `Values` phase using the `immediate` attribute set to `true`. For `UIOutput`,
>   the `conversion` happens in the `Render Response phase.`

Consider the snippet-

```
    <h:form>  
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.value}">
             <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" />
        </h:inputText>
         <br/><br/>

        <h:commandButton value="Send" action="#{bean.action()}"/>
    </h:form>
```

with the bean as

```
public class Bean{
    private Integer value = 24;
    // getters & setters
}
```

Firing a GET request.
I see that only `2 phases` are getting c/d

```
START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
```

For this specific `GET` request, where does the `conversion phase/ or just conversion` taking place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "conversion" is ambiguous here. For `UIInput`, it is talking about conversion from submitted value (HTTP request parameter) to model value (bean property). Here `Converter#getAsObject()` is used. For `UIOutput`, it is talking about conversion from model value (bean property) to string (HTML output). Here `Converter#getAsString()` is used.

As to your observation, it's helpful to realize that `UIInput` is a [subclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) of `UIOutput`. In other words, the conversion from model value to string is happening during render response.

Comment: Generally, for a custom convertor the call Converter#getAsObject() happens in the Process Validations Phase. Converter#getAsObject(), that will ofcourse happens in the RENDER response phase. This happens only for a POST request when data is submitted. Not GET request. And it does really makes sense. But I am talking about the case when I am using inbuilt convertors as above, which will convert the initial model value(24) into 24.00 for the initial GET request. Where did that actually happened?

Comment: During render response, as stated for `UIOutput`.

Comment: But  HtmlInputText is a direct subclass of UIInput.

Comment: Which is a subclass of `UIOutput`. See javadoc link in my answer. The class hierarchy is java.lang.Object
javax.faces.component.UIComponent
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase
**javax.faces.component.UIOutput**
javax.faces.component.UIInput. So, rules for `UIOutput` also apply to `UIInput`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to say. To put it that simple, your own words- For UIInput, it is talking about conversion from submitted value (HTTP request parameter) to model value (bean property). Here Converter#getAsObject() is used.                                       For the initial GET request, Converter#getAsObject()  wont' get c/d since there is no point of a value being submitted. But definitely will Converter#getAsString(). Is my understanding in this regard?

Comment: It will run when `<f:viewParam>` is used instead of `<h:inputXxx>` (do note that `<f:viewParam>` is also an instance of `UIInput`).

Comment: I think sometimes books(above extract was from Leonard's book) confuses a lot. Bu then I am able to learn properly(after clarification), Bauke Scholtz being on the stackoverflow. I personally prefer to write Bauke Scholtz rather than BalusC. :)

Comment: You're welcome :) "BalusC" is just a handle. Its uniqueness makes it easy to be used as search keyword.

Comment: I was wrong when I said this..... For the initial GET request, Converter#getAsObject() wont' get c/d since there is no point of a value being submitted..... It definitely gets c/d in the render response phase. I came to know only when I put a debug point in the method javax.faces.convert.NumberConvertor#getAsObject(). Thanks.